# Change layer background property based on UITableView selection?

Tags: ios

I have a view controller with two layers (topLayer and BottomLayer). On the bottom layer, I have a UITableView. I would like to change what buttons/labels are displayed on the topLayer, dependent on what is selected in the table view. I thought something like this should work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        self.topLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } 

}
```

But everytime that i run it, and select the first item in my tableview, it faults out (yes, i've defined and synthesized both topLayer and BottomLayer). Any ideas?

Comment: Any error codes?  Anything from the debugger?

Comment: I get a "Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint 3:" error, and is a greenbar highlighting the "self.topLayer.backgroudcolor..." line of code.

Comment: It is not crash. Remove the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, remove your break point and that should fix it.
Breakpoints, say run everything up to here. Then stop.
And it should work.